# Minimum re-labeling to make an array as close as possible to another one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, permutation

I have an array with unique labels in [0, n-1], say `arr1=[1, 0, 3, 2]` with n = 4. And then I have another array again with unique labels in [0, n-1], say `arr2=[0, 0, 2, 3]`. How can I find a re-labeling of arr2 in order to make it as close as possible to arr1 in terms of number of nonzero elements of their difference? For example, here the new arr2 is `arr2* = [0, 0, 3, 2]`.

Here is the code that I'm already using:

```
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 0, 3, 2])
n_labels = 4
perms = list(permutations(np.arange(n_labels)))
arr2 = np.array([0, 0, 2, 3]) 

best_perm = None
best_err = 1e8
for perm in perms:
    arr2_new = [perm[el] for el in arr2]
    err = np.linalg.norm(arr2_new - arr1, ord = 0)
    if err < best_err:
        best_err = err
        best_perm = perm
        if best_err == 0:
            break

arr2_new = [best_perm[el] for el in arr2]
```

Is there any way to make it more efficient?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimum re-labeling' - is there a limit on labels you can relabel, and what does 'as close to possible' mean - why is it not exactly same? In this case why is arr2* not same as arr1 after re-labeling?

Comment: I mean that each of the labels [0, 1, 2, 3] would be permuted for example as [1, 0, 3, 2]. That means, all 0s of arr2 would become 1, and so on and so forth. And arr2* does not need to match arr1. We need to find arr2* with the minimum l0 norm-distance from arr1.